# how to insert html tag in jquery value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Html tag

```
<span class="breakpoint"></span>
```

and i want to use this in lightslider at "verticalheight:". the code is below

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vertical').lightSlider({
      gallery:false,
      vertical:true,
      pager: false,
      item:6,
      verticalHeight:, # i want to use html tag here
      slideMargin:0,
      controls: true,
      prevHtml: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>',
      nextHtml: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>'
    });  
  });
</script>
```

can any one guide me how to solve this problem?...

Comment: Would be easier to help if you added the html code too.

Comment: <span class="breakpoint"></span>

Comment: What does it mean to use an HTML tag there? The value of that option has to be a number.

Comment: `verticalHeight: ` suppose to have a number as value like `slideMargin ` have. What do you mean by HTML tag here?

Comment: @Zico you are correct... it should be a number. I want responsive height so using breakpoint which results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated the value for vertical height should be a number. If you want to use a String value that's being populated into the html span tag, you would could first grab it's value then parse it as a number.

```
var vertHeight = parseInt($(".breakpoint").text(), 10);

//inside of lightSlider
verticalHeight: vertHeight
```

Comment: there is a problem with this,  value is not updating automatically... every time I need to reload the browser to load that specific value please can you sort this?  thank you

Comment: If the value inside of the html element "breakpoint" changes constantly while on the same page, you will need to have a event listener to get that value for you when it changes. I.E. if the value changes from "5" to "10", you will need a callback function to grab the new value of 10. Check if a new class is being added to the same element of "breakpoint" or refer to docs for lightslider on they deal with their event handling.

Comment: is it possible to reload "vertheight" on window resize using jquery or ajax

Comment: Yes, you can check for the size of the window with jquery's resize() function. You could use something like:
$(window).resize(function(){
    var mobileBreakPoint = 767;
    if($(this).width() == mobileBreakPoint ){
       vertHeight = 50px;
   }
});

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(".breakpoint")` to access the element.